Как скомпилировать и запустить отдельный .c файл в Clion?
Решаю задачи по книге "Язык программирования C", уже решённые задачи сохраняю и добавляю в отдельную папку отдельным .c файлом. Иногда возвращаюсь к уже решённым задачам и запускаю их (вспомнить как работают, ещё раз посмотреть реализацию и т.д.). Однако Clion не позволяет компилировать и запускать файлы отдельно, обязательно требует подключение файлов через CMake. Постоянно менять конфигурацию CMake очень неудобно. Может есть какой-то способ создать отдельную универсальную конфигурацию запуска файлов? К примеру через PS-скрипт?

gcc file.c...

Написать функцию или макрос, который будет добавлять executable, для каждого файла. Имя задавать по имени файла.

file (GLOB PROJECT_FILES *.c)

foreach (FILE_NAME IN LISTS PROJECT_FILES)
  get_filename_component(ONLY_FILE_NAME ${FILE_NAME} NAME) 
  add_executable (${ONLY_FILE_NAME} ${FILE_NAME})
endforeach ()

Примерно так, код пишу с телефона в работоспособности не уверен.
Убрать расширение файла:
file (GLOB PROJECT_FILES *.c)

foreach (FILE_NAME IN LISTS PROJECT_FILES)
  get_filename_component(ONLY_FILE_NAME ${FILE_NAME} NAME) 
  string (REPLACE ".c" "" FIXED_FILE_NAME ${ONLY_FILE_NAME})
  add_executable (${FIXED_FILE_NAME} ${FILE_NAME})
endforeach ()


это скрипт CLion?

Это часть CMakeLists

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(TutorC C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 23)
add_executable(TutorC main.c)
add_executable(TestC test.c)
file (GLOB PROJECT_FILES *.c)
foreach (FILE PROJECT_FILES)
add_executable (${FILE} ${FILE})
endforeach ()`
Теперь мой CMake выглядит так. При запуске выводит ошибку:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_executable):   Cannot find source file:     PROJECT_FILES CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_executable):   No SOURCES given to target: PROJECT_FILES

Попробуйте исправленный вариант.

После этих манипуляций, у вас должны появиться цели с именами файлов исходного кода. Например main.c.exe, модно ещё обрезать .с.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (string):
string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_executable):
The target name "C:/Users/minerin/CLionProjects/TutorC/main.c" is reserved
or not valid for certain CMake features, such as generator expressions, and
may result in undefined behavior.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_executable):
The target name "C:/Users/minerin/CLionProjects/TutorC/test.c" is reserved
or not valid for certain CMake features, such as generator expressions, and
may result in undefined behavior.

Исправил код. Предыдущий вариант отработал?

Работает! Может есть какая-то возможность скрыть плашку CLion о неподключённом файле? И можно ли подробностей, что вы конкретно изменили, очень уж интересно. Ваш ответ пометил

Как дома буду, напишу полноценный ответ, пока нет возможности, я на работе. А так, нужно читать книги по cmake, и ещё что за плашка о не подключённом файле?
